# Joining fields from two datasets and appending from one to other in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, table, append

I am looking to be able to append a field titled "premise ID" from one data set (from billing department) to the data set used in ArcMap. The data set provided from billing is taken and simplified (in Excel) down to the fields: ParcelID, Service Address, and Premises ID. The field sub-types are also matched in Excel to the data set used in ArcMap (found from ArcCatalog). We need to match the data based on the "Service Address" field and from there append the premise number FROM the simplified data set from billing TO the data set used in ArcMap.

We have tried the "append" geoprocessing tool from ArcToolbox with no luck as of yet.

We receive hundreds of new entries a month and are looking for the most efficient way to populate the premise ID field into our data set in ArcMap.

Comment: Have a read of Join Field https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000 It will do what you're after *but* it will join the contents of the table in its entireity, you will need to remove the fields you're not interested in. Note that Join Field is a many-to-one join relationship, if multiple possibilities exist in the input data only one will have its values copied.

Comment: Have you tried iterating "Add Join" or "Join FIeld" in ArcGIS modelBuilder? It would take in the data, much like for loop, then keep adding entries from each data, in each step/iteration.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an empty field "Premise_ID" in your GIS feature class.
2. Join the table that came from billing onto your attribute table. Note: joining on an address is risky because the values have to be completely identical, typos will hurt you. Safer to use the Parcel ID.
3. If you are repeating this periodically, use "select by attribute" to select only the records that don't already have a value in Premise_ID.
4. Use field calculator to set your new Premise_ID field equal to the premise ID value from the billing table.